# Style paper-input Polymer 1.0

Tags: html, css, polymer

how can I style a paper-input element, which is placed in my index.html file with my style.css file?

I tried the examples mentioned in the polymer docu like:

```css
paper-input.my-class {
        --paper-input-container-color: red;
        --paper-input-container-focus-color: blue;
        --paper-input-container-invalid-color: green;
        --paper-input-container-input-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<paper-input class="my-class" label="test" ></paper-input>
```

but nothing changes!

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style must be in a `<style is="custom-style">` or in a custom element's style for you to be able to use custom css properties.

[Here are the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-style) for more info.